# Начать воспроизведение первого byte[], как только он сформировался

Tags: android, java

Допустим, байты приходят из какого-то источника (аудио), складываются в одинаковые по размеру `byte[]`, и так в цикле, причем неизвестно, сколько всего байтов придет. Как начать воспроизведение первого `byte[]`, как только он сформировался? По окончании массива подавать ему следующий и так, чтобы не было разрыва в звуке. new `MediaPlayer()` не принимает `byte[]`.

Comment: Подозреваю, что всё это дело надо оформить потоком (stream).

Comment: Похоже, поможет класс AudioTrack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересный вопрос.

На ум приходят 3 варианта:

1. Организовать `ContentProvider` с кастомным `Uri` и подать плееру на вход `Uri`, но что-то подсказывает мне, что в этом случае будет очень больно и долго :)
2. Покопаться в Android NDK, где-то краем уха слышал, что там можно организовать подачу потока в плеер (не уверен).
3. Создать `MemoryFile`, над которым организовать `ParcelFileDescriptor`, который и подать на вход плееру. [См. пост на стэке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165216/what-is-the-use-of-memoryfile-in-android)